# Pegar conteúdo de campos de texto através do ID usando JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho um checkbox que na hora que seleciono e busco o valor no campo `type="text"`, um dos campos está funcionando perfeitamente mais o segundo campo não funciona.

```js
function pega(){
 var opcao = document.getElementById("opcao");
 var numero1 = document.getElementById("number1").value;
 var numero2 = document.getElementById("number2").value;

 if (opcao.checked == true){
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = numero1;
 }
  /*

 if (opcao.checked == true){
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = numero2;
 }*/

}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="opcao" name="Pacote" value="primeira opcao" onclick ="pega()">
<input type="text" id="number1" />

<input type="checkbox" id="opcao" name="Pacote" value="primeira opcao" onclick ="pega()">
<input type="text" id="number2" />
<div id="total"></div>
```

Minha ideia depois é calcular os dois campos, mas preciso saber se dessa forma que estou fazendo irei conseguir?

Comment: Você está usando o mesmo id para dois elementos diferentes, não faça isso. Nomeie cada um como opcao1 e opcao2, depois cheque se eles estao checked, como ja esta fazendo.

Comment: Primeiro, acho que você tinha que aceitar a resposta do @Sergio. Depois, por que você não usa jQuery? Por que você não coloca ***labels*** nos ***checkbox*** e pega o valor com `$("input[type='checkbox']").val();`ou outra variante jQuery, como `$(#idCheckbox).val();`? Se ao selecionar um ***checkbox*** o outro deve ser desmarcado, por que não usar `input[type="radio"]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Em HTML os IDs têm de ser únicos. Para agrupar elementos usa-se classes (`class`)  e para identificar de maneira unica usa-se `id`.

Assim o problema no teu código é que `.getElementById("opcao")` só vai retornar um elemento, o primeiro que encontrar.

Podes corrigir isso dando IDs diferentes, ou podes usar o facto de que quando a função `pega` pode receber o argumento `event` que é o evento que dispara esse `onclick`. E aí, a propriedade `.target` que te diz **qual** o elemento clicado. Assim `opção = e.target;`

Outra opção é fazer assim, que lê os valores de todos os `checkbox` independentemente de quantos forem:

```
var opcoes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');

function lerValores(els) {
  return [].map.call(els, function (el) {
    return el.checked;
  });

}

function pega(e) {
  var total = 0;
  lerValores(opcoes).forEach(function (checked, i) {
    if (checked) total += parseInt(inputs[i].value, 10);;
  });
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
}
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/pfb7sw78/

Comment: Sergio resolveu meu problema, mais não entendi o que esse cara faz ?

  function levarValores(els){
    return [].map.call(els, function(el) {
      return el.checked;
    });
  }

Comment: @DiBoa Essa função pega os valores das checkbox marcadas. Esses valores serão usados na outra função `pega ()`

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o que você deseja seja isso:

```js
function pega(){
    if (document.getElementById("opcao1").checked == true) {
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = document.getElementById('number1').value;
      }
    if (document.getElementById("opcao2").checked == true) {
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = document.getElementById('number2').value;;
      }
    
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="opcao1" name="pacote1" value="number1" onclick ="pega()">
<input type="text" id="number1" />

<input type="checkbox" id="opcao2" name="pacote2" value="number2" onclick ="pega()">
<input type="text" id="number2" />

<div id="total"></div>
```